# indexed column not in Ascending order

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which is having primary key and indexed with ascending order but when i write select query it doesn't not get displayed in ascending order.

[image: when select the table]

[image: Index added]

but in sql server, Primary key column will be displayed in ascending order. why not here? Am i missing anything ?

Comment: When you write select query, you always need use `ORDER BY` for guaranteed ordering rows

Comment: but in sqlserver, order by is not necessary when we have primary key and index

Comment: @King_Fisher It is always necessary to include an Order By if you want to *guarantee* the order. It just happens that in really simple queries, the easiest order for the DBMS to give you is the order of rows on disk, which happens to be convenient in the case of a Clustered Primary Key. This isn't something SQL Server ever promised you, it's just a lazy shortcut you got used to.

Comment: The **only** (really: the only) way to get a guaranteed order of the result is to use `order by` - that is true for SQL Server just as well as any other relational DBMS. There is no alternative to an `order by` if you want a **guaranteed** sort order.

Comment: @King_Fisher - absolutely false. SQL Server offers no such guarantees - you can find plenty of examples on this site where people have (re-)discovered that it's a faulty assumption.

Comment: I have seen many times when a column having clustered index with asc/desc, It will results based on the index when we query without orderby . Im very sure about SQLServer

Comment: @King_Fisher Did you read my answer yet? I explain exactly why that is *likely* to happen, *most* of the time. That doesn't mean it's *guaranteed* to happen, and you should not be surprised when another DBMS, or even a more complex query on that same table, doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: @King_Fisher: you might have seen this happen, but there is no **guarantee** whatsoever that this will happen all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rows in a table do not have a specific order (well, they might underneath, but they don't need to, and the DBMS has no obligation to tell you what it is).

The order of *results* from a query is specified by the `ORDER BY` clause that you supply. If you don't use an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, the DBMS is free to return the results in whatever order it likes. For a simple query, this will *often* be the order they exist on disk, although as soon as you go beyond `SELECT *` from a single table, it will probably be something completely different.

What you probably had in SQL Server is a "clustered index", which isn't really an index at all, it's an instruction to store the rows on disk in a specific order for faster access. Since they'll generally be retrieved from disk in that order, a (simple) query with no `ORDER BY` will *usually* end up displaying them in that order. It's not something you should ever rely on, though.

The order of rows on disk is particularly unlikely to be useful in Postgres, because it uses something called "MVCC", where updating a row actually creates a new record on disk and marks the old one as inactive (it's a way of handling transactions without locking the table). This makes the contrast particularly obvious, but the rule is the same in any DBMS: **If you want a particular order of results, use `ORDER BY`**.

Comment: Fine, I can use order by. I just wondered why it's behaving differently.  Thanks

Comment: @King_Fisher And hopefully, now you know :)

Comment: I agreed fourth point you mentioned. That's y it display the last modified record at last when select without order by

Comment: So the table size will not be increased? If I update records frequently

Comment: Thank you for the reference

Comment: @King_Fisher [This comment posted prematurely while I was adding another link] That's the topic for a different question, but you might want to read [the official intro to MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html), and [about "vacuuming"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html). In short: rest assured, it's not as daft an idea as it sounds, else Postgres would never have got so popular; but, yes, it does have different performance implications than purely lock-based solutions in other DBMSes.

Answer (score 1):

- When building indexes often the default options are used to create an
  index which creates the index in ascending order.  This is usually
  the most logical way of creating an index, so the newest data or
  smallest value is at the top and the oldest or biggest value is at
  the end.  Although searching an index works great by creating an
  index this way, but have you ever thought about the need to always
  return the most recent data first.
  for more details visit the page:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1337/building-sql-server-indexes-in-ascending-vs-descending-order/

- Indexing is basically used to internal db process to access the data 
  in faster way. This is not going to be display as the data as    per 
  indexes.
- For the displaying the records in ascending descending order need to
  write manually.